# Where is the actual HTML markup of a web page contained in HTTP?

Tags: html, http, browser, get

say I type "stackoverflow.com" in Firefox.

I know I am sending an HTTP GET request. However, where is the actual HTML markup located in the response? Is it in a certain header like content-type? Or is it located elsewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP responses have the following data:

- A HTTP version
- A status code + sometimes a human readable status string
- Headers
- A body

Html is in the response body

Answer (score 0):

HTML is in response body.

There is an example in [Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol, wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Web Broswer read a response message.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
  <head>
    <title>An Example Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```